# Images are being placed on top of each other after using the position property on CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position, css-position

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>...</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- My Styles -->
    <style>
        .boxWrap {
            position: relative;
        }

        .boxItem {
            position: absolute;
        }  

        h1 {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 boxWrap">
                <div class="boxWrap">
                    <img src="01.png" class="img-fluid boxItem" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 boxWrap">
                <div class="boxWrap">
                    <img src="01.png" class="img-fluid boxItem" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 boxWrap">
                <div class="boxWrap">
                    <img src="01.png" class="img-fluid boxItem" alt="">
                    <h1 class="boxItem">hello</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 boxWrap">
                <div class="boxWrap">
                    <img src="01.png" class="img-fluid boxItem" alt="">
                    <h1 class="boxItem">hello</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ok so I've been trying to put text inside and image by using the position property in CSS. Basically, I gave the image's parent a value of "relative" and a value of "absolute" to the images. It turns out that no matter how many element I put "after" the first "boxWrap" div, they always get placed on top of first div with that class. How can I restore the normal flow of the page?

Comment: Could you show a snapshot of how the images are lapping unto each other? Also, what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if everything inside an element is positioned absolutely, the element effectively no longer has any content, so its height will be 0.
In other words, all your boxWrap divs have height 0 and the imgs inside are all on the same spot in the window, overflowing out of their divs.

Solution: don't position the images absolutely, so that they do take up space in the divs, and place the absolutely positioned texts in the right position by using `top` and `left`.

```css
.boxWrap {
  position: relative;
}

.boxItem {
  /* no styles for boxItem */
}

/* new class boxText */
.boxText {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 boxWrap">
      <div class="boxWrap">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-fluid boxItem" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 boxWrap">
      <div class="boxWrap">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-fluid boxItem" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 boxWrap">
      <div class="boxWrap">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-fluid boxItem" alt="">
        <h1 class="boxText">hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 boxWrap">
      <div class="boxWrap">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" class="img-fluid boxItem" alt="">
        <h1 class="boxText">hello</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```